# Vb.net I cannot return datarows from access when searching for boolean true value

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I've google searched and searched here, but I'm not sure of the terminology to use, so I'm not having luck with search results.

I'm writing a front end to an access database.  It's logging product change requests. The process flow is something like this - any user submits a request, and the status of the request is set to "request"  an administrator then evaluates the requests and determines if more information is needed to proceed, if we are going to proceed without additional info, or if the request is denied. If more information is needed - he/she may check a box for laborCost as an example.  When they 'submit' updates (saves changes back to database) my code then should email those tied to labor to inform them to supply a value for further review. It then sets the status to pending.

The way I am attempting this - is with a users table (tblusers) It has access yes/no boxes for EngCost, MatlCost, LaborCost, and ToolCost.

If the labor box is checked on the PCR form - I am then attempting to look at the users table via a dataset - look at the column for laborcost and return all of the "true" values - so that I can 'return' a string to populate an outlook "Send to:" email.

here's my code so far

```
 Public Function sendto(field As String)

    Dim foundrows() As Data.DataRow
    'Dim e() As String
    ' Dim es As String
    'Dim fltr As Boolean = True

    foundrows = DsPcrMaintenance.Tables("tblUsers").Select(field & "<> 0")


    For i As Integer = 0 To foundrows.Count - 1

        e(i) = DsPcrMaintenance.Tables("tblusers").Rows(i)("email")

    Next
```

for all of the rows found, I'm wanting to grab the email address from that row, then combine that array to a string of addresses for my sendto.

I'm passing the column name into the function using 'field' and that works -
Field in this case is "laborCost"  and I'm adding <>0 so it's not false.
but I'm getting 'nothing' for foundrows.  I've tried field & "<> '0'", I've tried true and false, 0 and -1, and I can't get a result.

essentially, I want to lookup the true value of the grouping, then for each row returned, build my "to:" email string.  user@company.com; user@company.com etc.

Most of the categories have more than one send to.  Sorry for the long post -trying to be thorough.

Comment: What is the Datatype of the field _laborCost_ in your database table?

Comment: In access - it's a Boolean yes/no field.

Comment: Then <> 0 should work. Did you try to debug this code? In particular how many rows are present in the _DsPcrMaintenance.Tables("tblUsers")_ at the moment of the call to Select?

Comment: The user table has 21 records.  In this instance, I'm looking for EngCost which currently only has 1 user checked.  In debugging, I still get foundrows = nothing. using "EngCost <> 0" as my filter string. I'm trying to paste in screen shot below.

Comment: Can't add screen shot.

Comment: Ok - here lies the issue - access has 21 records.  Debugging, dsPcrMaintenance.tables("tblUsers") has 0 row count.  it's filled on form load.... so I'm not sure what's going on now - more lost then before.

Comment: I got the table to now have rows in the debugger.  It was missing a table adapter on the form.  I use that same table 2 other times for lookups - to populate an assigned to team lead and assigned to subordinate field. In the debugger I can preview the data - and it shows text in the fields as true and false.  I tried setting criteria to = true or <> False and still get no foundrows.

Comment: Use <> 0 and check the loop. You should use the foundRows array not the datatable rows to extract the emails

Comment: the `.Select(field & "<> 0")` looks fine to be honest as long as there are rows in the datatable which you have said there now is. One thing you might hit next though is `e(i) = DsPcrMaintenance.Tables("tblusers").Rows(i)("email")` You will need to use `foundrows` in your loop not the original table. Also you will need to `ReDim e(foundrows.count - 1)` just before the loop code (obviously check that foundrows has rows first before the `ReDim`).

Comment: Ok, I changed the order of my variable declarations, and I got a row populated into foundrows.  at least the count now says 1 instead of 0.  Now, how do I select the email column name from the found row?  If I swap the dspcrmaintenance.tables from the e(I) line, then I get an error that rows in not part of datarow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop you shoud use the *foundRows* not on the rows of the original table

```
Redim e(foundRows.Length)
For i As Integer = 0 To foundrows.Count - 1

    If Not IsDBNull(foundRows(i)("email")) Then
        e(i) = foundRows(i)("email").ToString()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the reason for the redim - when I hadn't used e until this line.  but, I thank you for your patience, as it does appear to be working now.

Comment: the array _e_, when initially declared, has a length. In other words, when you declare an array you should define the number of elements that you want to store in that array. If you have more elements to store then you have a problem because the array, without a Redim, cannot store more elements than the size initially declared. Due to the dynamic nature of this code you cannot know exactly how many elements you want to store thus you need a Redim to be safe. But this is the main reason behind the popularity of the generic collections like the List(Of String) that doesn't need a resize